# FullCalender does not display events from Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs3, fullcalendar, vite

I am currently building a calendar app with FullCalendar. My backend is Firebase Firestore. I'm trying to display the events I get from Firebase but that's not working.

**Tech stack:**
Vue 3 Composition API
Vite
Vuetify
Tailwind
Typescript

I let in the "onMounted" after the "getEvents" output the events to me in the console. The events come from Firebase and this works as you can see in the console.

The first one is the event array itself from Firebase:
[image: Event from Firebase]

The second is the event array in the object "calendarPlugins".
[image: Event in Object]

Although it has the same structure and is in the object it does not work.

I have also hardcoded an event for test purposes

The first event is the hardcoded array:
[image: Hardcoded event]

The second one is the hardcoded event array in the object "calendarPlugins".
[image: Hardcoded event in Object]

But here it works although the structure and everything is the same. Am I forgetting something or did I miss something?

Here is my code:

**Calendar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="calendar">
    <FullCalendar :options="calendarPlugins" />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { db } from "../main";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";

import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue3";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";
import deLocale from "@fullcalendar/core/locales/de";

let events: any = [];

const event = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "Test",
    description: "Test",
    start: "2023-03-03",
    end: "2023-03-10",
    backgroundColor: "#1976D2",
  },
];

const getEvents = () => {
  db.collection("MYEVENT")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        events.push({
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          description: doc.data().description,
          start: doc.data().start,
          end: doc.data().end,
          backgroundColor: doc.data().backgroundColor,
        });
      });
    });
};

const calendarPlugins = {
  plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
  initialView: "dayGridMonth",
  headerToolbar: {
    left: "prev,next,today",
    center: "title",
    right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
  },
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,
  locale: deLocale,
  events: events, //event is the hardcoded event
};

onMounted(() => {
  getEvents();
  console.log(events); //event is the hardcoded event
  console.log(calendarPlugins);
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

**main.ts**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "./style.css";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router/index.js";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "MY_API_KEY",
  authDomain: "MY_AUTH_DOMAIN",
  projectId: "MY_PROJECT_ID",
  storageBucket: "MY_STORAGE_BUCKET.",
  messagingSenderId: "MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID",
  appId: "MY_APP_ID",
});

export const db = firebase.firestore();

createApp(App)
.use(router)
.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a vue user, so the trail is not 100% clear to me, but I suspect the issue may be that you're initialising the calendar before calling getEvents, and therefore it's not passing the data to fullCalendar, because fullCalendar ingested `events` before it was populated. You also have to remember that your firebase query runs asynchronously, so other code on the page won't wait for it to complete.

Normally, to integrate an event feed with fullCalendar the best way is to provide a dynamic feed, which fullCalendar can then call as and when it needs to fetch events. In your case the [events as a function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function) style will be the best, so you can put your request to firebase in the callback function, and then pass the events to fullCalendar (via the additional callback supplied to you) when the asynchronous request returns.

Something like this:

```
events: function( fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback ) { 
  db.collection("MYEVENT")
    .get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      let events = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        events.push({
          id: doc.id,
          title: doc.data().title,
          description: doc.data().description,
          start: doc.data().start,
          end: doc.data().end,
          backgroundColor: doc.data().backgroundColor,
        });
      });
      successCallback(events);
    });
}
```

You then don't need the `const getEvents = () => {` etc.

P.S. This pattern also gives you the ability, if you wish, to use the supplied start and end dates to restrict the data you download from firebase to only those events which fall between those dates. This can be more efficient, especially when you have a large database of events after a while, so you don't download redundant data unnecessarily. If it turns out that the user then changes the date range to another month/week/day outside the initial range, then it simply runs the callback again and supplies new dates, and downloads the extra data from the server.